# How do I bind a CLI command to a key in PhpStorm?

Tags: php, command-line-interface, phpstorm

I have a console command set up in my Larval App to reseed the test database when required.

`$ app reseed connection=default`

Is it possible to run perform the command with a key combo in PhpStorm?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the typically question which response is : [Remote SSH External Tools](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Using+the+PhpStorm+built-in+SSH+terminal+and+remote+SSH+external+tools)

With this tool PHPStorm you can launch and execute any shell command which commonly launch into terminal.

You can manage cache, fixtures, database, laravel or symfony command and perhaps also DB command.

Good luck